# ViewFlipper does not flip when has a TextEdit on it

Tags: android, swipe, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper that hold a TextEdit that fills the parent.
When i swipe on the TextEdit it pops the keyboard to enter text, but i want to flip the view on swipe.
How can i implement this functionality?
Should i implement Gesture detection for the EditText or is there a way to ignore or pass the touch event to the parent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If You set the Layout of Your EditText View to Match_Parent, then there is no possibility, to touch besides the view, so it automatically opens the keyboard. What You can do is to minimize the EditText and center it inside the ViewFlipper, so there is a little bit place besides the view. Another solution is to disable EditText on your ViewFlippers Gesture Event and enable it if the event has done. But I didn´t try this, it´s just an idea.

Comment: How do i disable the gesture event?

Comment: I meant not to disable the gesture Event, I meant to disable the EditText, so it does not open the keyboard on touch event.